# Internet is very slow in webkit browsers when connecting with proxy

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, safari, webkit

Chrome Version:29.0.1547.66 (Official Build 220848) m
Operating System :Windows 7

Internet is very slow in my webkit browsers such as Chrome and safari when connecting internet with proxy, but Internet is very fast in IE8 and Firefox 23.

Also Internet in chrome and safari is fast when i use "Automatically detect settings" in Internet options>>>connections>>>LAN settings, but i want to connect internet via proxy only as some of my work sites are allowed only in proxy.

and I am facing slow in internet from applications also when trying with proxy, but fast only in IE and Firefox.

I kept chrome as my default browser.

Note:

1. I installed chrome by standalone installer, not from cloud service.

Please help me to make my internet fast when connecting via proxy in chrome and safari.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. Now Internet connection is fast as usual in chrome and safari.

Issue is because of Windows7 service Pack 1 which is causing the issue.

Solution:

> Run command prompt as Administrator
>    Type the following: "netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled"
>    You should see 'Ok' appear

Please see this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a3d38345-cf76-4fb2-806b-b2bcb51bc2cd/windows-7-service-pack-1-internet-connectivity-issues